# Expression for an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations, algebra, variational-calculus

I am facing a problem obtaining an expression for my integral. My code goes in a time-consuming loop whenever I execute this integral. The code is:

```
P=-(2 r^8 s^6 x^2 (r^2 - x^2)^2)/(3 \[Pi] (r^6 (-1 + s^2) - 
  2 r^3 (s + r (-1 + s^2)) x^2 + (r (-1 + s) + s) (r + (-1 + r) s) x^4)^3) #1st expression
j=1/s + x^2/(r^3 - r x^2)#second expression
```

The code I use for integration is:

```
e=Re[Integrate[P*j,{x,-1,1}]]
```

I need a result, that should be a function, e(s,r), of r and s as an answer. The code goes into an infinite loop. P.S. I am using Mat 9.0, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Please do not use all capital letters in the title.

Comment: What is the intent of the `#second expression` portion of your code?

Comment: Lots of integrands can’t be analytically integrated. Do you have some reason to think that this one can be?

Comment: `expr=Apart[FullSimplify[P*j]]; Integrate[expr[[i]],{x,-1,1}]//InputForm` where you substitute any 1,2,3,4,5,6 for `i` will break your integrand apart into the sum of six smaller rationals and `Integrate` will handle any one of those in half a minute. Then the `InputForm` will show you all the conditions that must be true for that result to be valid. You can study the conditions for all six of those and try to make certain that your actual problem satisfies all those conditions. Test this to make certain that it is correct before you trust any of this. The `FullSimplify` may not be needed.

Comment: I am not a very experience user but Mathematica faces much less problems with antiderivative than with definite integrals.

In your case, there is no problem even without partial fraction decomposition to obtain the antiderivative. Using the expression, use the bounds to obtain the definite integral as a function of $r$ and $s$..

Comment: Thanks, guys, I got the answer by using the term Integrate with undefined limits. Then I evaluated the limits by subtraction.
Thanks again, all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Bill's hint (see comments) and together with assumption `Element[{r, s}, Reals]` Mathematica v12.2 evaluates the integral after a while (23.4s)

```
expr = Apart[FullSimplify[P*j]];
int = Sum[Simplify@Integrate[expr[[i]], {x, -1, 1},Assumptions -> Element[{r, s}, Reals]], {i, 1, Length[expr]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The antidericative requires  $6.47$ seconds and the definite integral $0.17$ extra seconds using `Limit[.]` . I have a slow machine

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Don't forget the time to check for singularities inside the integration range!